Swap C++ function parameters using regex
I'm trying to swap the arguments to function GetNumberOfMilliSeconds() using a regular expression. Currently I'm doing it by using macros and copying the first and second parameters into different registers and pasting them in reverse order. Something like this:
qq       # start recording macro q
0f"      # move to first "
"adW     # delete first argument into register a
"bdW     # delete second argument into register b
"bP      # paste content of register b
i,<Esc>  # insert ,
"aP      # paste content of register a
xx       # delete the extra comma at the end

But I feel it can be done more elegantly using a regular expression. Can someone please let me know how I can do this using Vim's regular expression?
Here is the the code:
std::int64_t GetNumberOfMilliSeconds( const std::string& timestamp, const std::string& date )
{
}

GetNumberOfMilliSeconds( "230394", "123519.050" ),
GetNumberOfMilliSeconds( "080301", "223614.954" ),
GetNumberOfMilliSeconds( "220515", "092751.123" ),
GetNumberOfMilliSeconds( "130220", "182309.098" ),
GetNumberOfMilliSeconds( "210920", "083559.0" ),
GetNumberOfMilliSeconds( "250622", "153516.101" ),
GetNumberOfMilliSeconds( "121220", "091213.789" ),
GetNumberOfMilliSeconds( "040722", "203014.333" ),


I would select the lines where the arguments need to be swapped and run:
:'<,'>s/\v"([^"]*)",\s*"([^"]*)"/"\2", "\1"/

or:
'<,'>s/\v\(\s*\zs([^, ]*),\s*([^, )]*)/\2, \1/


\v turns the very magic mode (in order to be able to use capturing brace ( without having to escape them)
\(\s* detect the beginning of the arguments part
\zs starts the replacing pattern
([^, ]*) capture the first argument
,\s* capture the argument separator
([^, )]*) capture the second argument


For the example at hand, the command can even be simplified to '<,'>s/\v(".*"), (".*")/\2, \1.
